# Execute a script only once in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, if-statement, geofire

On my application developed in swift, I would like to be able to execute a script once, it is a request GeoFire and I would like that it makes its request once then stops. I tried conditions and loops

```
if ([name of the varialble] <= 1)
{
// Execute the query,
}
else if ([name of the variable > 1)
{
// Otherwise stop the query
}
```

But that never works.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

You can use `dispatch_once` in your `viewDidLoad:`

```
static dispatch_once_t once;
dispatch_once(&once, ^
{
    // Code to run once
});
```

This will make the code run only once until you exit and close your app.